# How do I write a file to my server with the contents from a form?

Tags: php, apache, cgi

Ok, So I'm setting up a device that has Wi-Fi and an ePaper display.

Usually, the device connects to the internet via Wi-Fi, and everything procedes according to plan. Occasionally, however, I want to take my device to a new location with a different Wi-Fi connection.

What I want to achieve is:

1. The device recognises that it has lost connectivity and does a quick
   scan of available Access Points in the area.
2. It then disables it's client Wi-Fi settings, Enables a Wi-Fi hot-spot and displays a QR
   code on the display for a smart phone to connect.
3. The smart phone user then selects the Wi-Fi access point from the list scanned in step 1 above (displayed in web page format).
4. The user then enters the password for that Access Point.
5. At this point the device attempts to connect to that AP and life goes on.

Right now, I'm having a problem getting the selected Wi-Fi connection and password saved onto the web server (step 4).

I've kind of realised that I need to use PHP and CGI, However, all the code that I've tried has not created any files on my device (Apache web server).

Most recently, I've tried dialing it all the way back and just hard coding what and where I want it to save, and still getting no joy:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>some test</h1>
        <form method="post">
           Access Point Password:<br>
          <input type="text" name="passwd" id="passwd" size="40"><br>
          <input type="submit" name="save">
        </form>
  </body>
</html>

<?php
    $passwd = $_POST['passwd'];
    $fp = fopen('/tmp/wifi.pwd', 'a');
    fwrite($fp, $passwd);
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

My PHP version is `PHP 7.3.27-1~deb10u1 (cli) (built: Feb 13 2021 16:31:40) ( NTS )`

The device is running `Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)`

Properties on `/tmp/` are `drwxrwxrwt`, so anyone should be able to create files there.

One more note - I **cannot** use a database to accomplish this. It needs to be done as plaintext.

======UPDATE======
Ok, sorry about the delay, new job, lots of training, lots of work, very little time for family, even less for *me*

So I've been playing around (a lot) with the code. - I've updated the above with the code I'm currently using

I've also tried:

```
<?php
    print_r($_POST);
    if( !empty($_POST['passwd']) ) {
        $passwd = $_POST['passwd'];
        file_put_contents("/tmp/wifi.pwd", $passwd . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Still no file creation.

Comment: Did you look in the PHP Error log yet?

Comment: Would be interesting to see the full function code as well

Comment: I have not; It's been a while since I've done PHP work and forgot it existed. I'll look into it and add any more info here when I have it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Question updated with error log

Comment: @RiggsFolly the full code is... messy, plus the code is not all in one location and spans across many file locations. It's also in BASH. I don't use Python, so I'm going to avoid that whole kettle right there. ALso there's lots of dead code that needs to be cleaned up once I've actually got this working. I might publish publicly to Github once that's done though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'm a little disappointed and even a little angry that this was the answer because it's a limitation in the program itself that provides no errors, warnings or notifications.

I managed to find my answer in a buried answer to another question with NO upvotes on it. (Needless to say it's got an upvote NOW!)

I'm not even going to link to the quesiton asked there, but the answer provided that solved the problem I was having.

https://askubuntu.com/a/1138314/548774

The bottom line is that **Apache2 will NOT WRITE TO ANYWHERE ON THE FILE SYSTEM OTHER THAN /var/www/ OR A SUB DIRECTORY**

The errors that I was experiencing with PHP are because I introduced them trying to troubleshoot why it would not write the file to /tmp/.

Answer (score 0):

`Undefined index: passwd in /var/www/html/net/1.php on line 240`
That means `$_POST` array exists, but the `'passwd'` is not in it. Do a `print_r($_POST);` to what is posted then.

Check your php.ini and make sure `post_max_size` is not 0.

Note the first time you load the page, `$_POST` will be empty. So once you will see this error message for sure. The `$_POST` will only contain data when you submitted the form.
If you want to avoid that error message the first time, then do

```
if( !empty($_POST['passwd']) ) {
  $passwd = $_POST['passwd'];
  ...
  fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: So Now I'm getting `Notice: Undefined variable: array in /var/www/html/net/1.php on line 227` (lower line number as I took some other stuff out above it). My post_max_size is set to `8M`: 
post_max_size = 8M

Comment: OK, on 1st page load, I'm now getting `Array ( )`, after data "`019`" is entered, I'm getting `Array ( [passwd] => 019 [submit] => Submit )`. I'm still not getting any file creation in `/tmp/` though. I've even tried `chown -R www-data:www-data /tmp/` to make apache the owner of the `/tmp/` directory, it didn't work. (changed it back to root:root)